# Trouble with Prepared Statements in

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website interface to allow my colleagues to easily add tuples to the database. I don't understand why this code isn't working and I was hoping someone could help me please. Thanks.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO animal (MouseID,birthDate,harvestDate,injectionDate1,
    injectionDate2,injectionDate3,Adjuvant,Target,Gender,Age,animalType,
    Titer,antibodyType) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('sssssssssisss', $_POST['mouseid'], $_POST['birthdate'], $_POST['harvestdate'], $_POST['injectiondate1'], $_POST['injectiondate2'],
     $_POST['injectiondate3'], $_POST['adjuvant'], $_POST['target'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['animaltype'], $_POST['titer'], $_POST['antibodytype']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();
```

Comment: What's not working?  What happens?  Do you see any  errors?  Try adding in error checking (never assume any database call worked).  `if($statement === FALSE){ die($databaseConnection->error()); }` and `if($statement->execute() === FALSE){ die($statement->error()); }`.

Comment: Not enough information to help you...

Comment: You need to use bindvalue to bind values for an INSERT/UPDATE/REPLACE query. bind_param() is used to bind columns of a SELECT result. http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Sorry guys, this is my first time asking a question. If i don't use a prepared statement I am able to execute this query to the database. I thought I was doing something syntactically wrong. I know for a fact that this segment of the code is not working correctly and it's just not adding anything to the table so that is why I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: PDO's named placeholders are generally more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

bind_param requires references:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO animal (MouseID,birthDate,harvestDate,injectionDate1,
    injectionDate2,injectionDate3,Adjuvant,Target,Gender,Age,animalType,
    Titer,antibodyType) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('sssssssssisss', &$_POST['mouseid'], &$_POST['birthdate'],
  &$_POST['harvestdate'], &$_POST['injectiondate1'], &$_POST['injectiondate2'],
  &$_POST['injectiondate3'], &$_POST['adjuvant'], &$_POST['target'], &$_POST['gender'],
  &$_POST['age'], &$_POST['animaltype'], &$_POST['titer'], &$_POST['antibodytype']);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
```

Comment: Formatting is a bit of a disaster here. In a pinch `{}` usually fixes it in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking whether the `prepare` and `execute` functions succeeded or not.

If you aren't going to check the return from those function, you can have PDO automatically do the check, and raise an exception if an database error occurs, by setting attributes on the connection:

```
$databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

If you don't check the return from the functions, then your code is effectively "swallowing" any database errors that happen.

Setting these connection attributes isn't the only approach to handling database errors, and it isn't always the most appropriate approach.

Another alternative is to explicitly check the return from the functions in your code, for example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ... ";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt) {
   print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}

if(!$stmt->execute()) {
   print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

Using one of these approaches, it's likely to be revealed that a database error is occurring. The actual error code and message will help determine what the actual problem is. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: @spencer753 and others. I know for a fact that it is an execution failure because there is something wrong with the bind_param()

Comment: @javidaceil: and what is the actual database error that is being returned?

Comment: I dont know. improper syntax most likely. I've been stuck here for like two hours, gone through at least a dozen examples and they all work unless i'm trying to use a prepared statement in this format.

Comment: I recognize now (finally) that you are using **mysqli** and not **PDO** interface.  (PDO has `bindParam` function, mysqli has `bind_param` function`.) So my suggestion for setting PDO connection attributes isn't applicable. With mysqli, you'd use `$mysqli->error()` to get the last error.

Comment: I see and I got it to work. it wouldn't allow submission unless all fields had values although i had allowed some of the fields to be NULL. i'll look more into that later, thank you very much spencer

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what "wouldn't allow submission" means, whether that means there's some javascript code that was checking values on the form, or whether that means there was database error returned when the `$sth->execute()` function was called. (But, we wouldn't typically refer to an error returned by a SQL INSERT statement as "wouldn't allow submission"; we'd typically report that as MySQL error, frequently "You have an error in your SQL syntax;...", "Error 1022 Can't write; duplicate key", etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using PDO, the correct procedure here is passing all the values to the execute() method as an array:

```
$statement->execute(array('sssssssssisss', $_POST['mouseid'], [...]));
```

Or use bindParam()/bindValue() for every single value, but then you have to use named parameters (:parametername).

For the future: Checking the return values of all the methods, enabling error reporting / logging, making PDO throw exceptions on errors (`$databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`) and finally posting any appearing Error Messages with your question, help a lot in answering it.